# Is there any way to maintain session in angular 5 application without using LocalStorage or SessionStorage?

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to use some values which are getting after login throughout the application. But I don't want to store those in browser storage. So is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: without localstorage and sessionstorage when you refresh page, variable lost

Comment: Make a singleton user service that is provided in root, then use it across the app to share the credentials. But you will lose the values on refresh, you will have to wire it so that user service makes a fresh call on refresh, or whenever credentials are unavailable.

Comment: @Hien Nguyen Yeah I know but it wont be secure if I store values there, that's why I am searching for other ways.

Comment: @sabithpocker Thanks for your suggestion, but can you explain how can I wire it even on refresh?

Comment: You have to make a call to your API, if the user session is active it can respond with a User object, otherwise redirect to login page. Using singleton or even memoization wont help with retaining variables across browsing sessions or across refresh. Also I guess Session Storage is made for such purposes, which gets destroyed after each session with [some edge cases](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/36962).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a service with `providedIn: 'root'` then it will be a singleton across your app. You can then store state in this service:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {
  private userSettings: any;

  public setUserSettings(userSettings: any) {
    this.userSettings = userSettings;
  }

  public getUserSettings() {
    return this.userSettings;
  }
}
```

Of course if the browser tab is refreshed the app is completely reloaded and any state will be lost - if you need to persist state between sessions like this then you should use local storage.